# Test automatically web services with JUnit

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests

I have a lot of webServices that I want to test with Junit. For each webService I have between 5 and 40 tests to do, and writing those tests by hand take a lot of time and it is very tedious to do because they are almost the same.

In fact, I send an xml request to my web service, get the response and compare it with the one expected. So for each test, I need only the webService URL, the body of the request and the response expected.

What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good way to do this. I use [JUnit parameterized tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html). [This](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) is a good tutorial to learn how to implement those tests.

I use also generic methods that read a WSDL file and retrieve the types needed to do my tests.
So now I have just one generic parameterized test for all my webServices, and parameters are paths of my WSDL files, input files and expected output files.

Comment: Is there a way to test a web service without having to generate the stub code using wsimport (every single time)? A generic code that just accepts the wsdl url.